# SSRS - Remote Execution Powershell Script that Uploads RDL files to SSRS server fails but execution via RDP works

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell script that uses the [ReportingServicesTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) module to interact with SSRS. The script essentially connects to an SSRS server and uploads some RDL files.

I'm using **Azure DevOps pipelines** to execute this script on different environments (QA and PROD), it works flawlessly in QA. However the same setup isn't working on our Production environment.

The first part of the script where it imports the SSRS module works, I can see the verbose log commands of all the functions getting loaded but the script fails when it reaches the part where it tries to connect to the SSRS server.

Now **if I RDP to the PROD server** and execute the same script there with the same parameters, the same service account, **the entire script works fine** and it **uploads the RDL file to SSRS**. I have no idea what is different and what is causing it to fail when executed from the pipeline.

I've designed the pipeline for both environments like this:

- Windows Machine File Copy - Copies the RDL files from the agent to the required remote server
- Run Powershell On Target Machine - Execute a PS script on a remote machine

I'm using the same credentials in all tasks and situations mentioned above.

Script:

```
param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
       [string]$ModuleFilePath,
            
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
       [string]$ArtifactPath,
            
       [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
       [string]$ReportServerURI
    )
       
    # Import the SSRS tools module
    Import-Module $ModuleFilePath
       
    # Function to create new folders inside SSRS
    function New-Folder {
      # saving space by leaving this out, not relevant
    }
    # Check connection to the Report Server
    try {
        Connect-RsReportServer -ReportServerUri $ReportServerURI
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
        Write-Host "Error Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        if ($_.Exception.InnerException) {
            Write-Host "Inner Exception: $($_.Exception.InnerException.Message)"
        }
        Write-Host "Error connecting to the SSRS Server"
        Exit(1)
    }
    
    # Upload RDL file, again leaving this part out as it doesn't even reach this point
    


 Following is the Log from Azure DevOps:
    ...
    VERBOSE: Importing function 'Write-RsRestFolderContent'.
    VERBOSE: Establishing proxy connection to 
    https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx...
    Error Type: System.Exception
    Error Message: Failed to establish proxy connection to https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer : Failed to establish proxy connection to https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an error downloading 'https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx'.
    Inner Exception: Failed to establish proxy connection to https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx : There was an error downloading 'https://<URL-REDACTED>/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx'.
    Error connecting to the SSRS Server
    ##[debug][<REDACTED>]LASTEXITCODE is 1
```

Comment: You are going through a proxy and connection is not completing.  It could be a TLS issue.  What OS are you using?  Check log files in SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio.  The log files are in the explorer under Management.  See if there is an error a the same time you run code.  There should be a User and Group login shown in the log files.   See if you get the same user and group when code works.  If you do not see an entry in the log file than connection never completes.

Comment: We're using a Windows Server (I'll have to check the year). Thank you the suggestion! Will definitely have a look at those logs now!

Comment: There was nothing in the logs and as you mentioned at the end of your comment, it definitely is a connection issue. So we're gonna try something else. Thanks for the inputs though I really appreciate it! @jdweng

Comment: SSRS also has log files.  You can find then in the Start Button.  They use to be under Microsoft but may under SSRS.